# "Transport the product with other products" or "transport the product along with other products"?

Tags: prepositions, difference

Could you tell me if there is any difference between *transport the product with other products* or *transport the product along with other products*? For example:

> When you transport the product **with** other products, make sure they are divided.
>
> When you transport the product **along with** other products, make sure they are divided.

Are both perfectly acceptable?

Comment: I always think of 'along with' as one of those commentator fillers - they add nothing except to fill in airtime when they may otherwise run out of things to say. That said, your sentence is troublesome. Replace 'product' with 'eggs' & 'coal' & see how it fails to specify what this 'division' consists of.

Comment: You can use any of ***with, along with, together with, alongside*** (and probably other prepositions). It doesn't really make any difference.

Comment: You don't have to repeat 'product', you can say 'transport the product [along] with **others**'.

Comment: Both are correct. However, "along with" usually has the more abstract meaning, "at the same time", or "in conjunction with", so it's not as natural as "with"